# write query in SQL to implement three sumifs function

Tags: sql, sum

I have a table which is similar like this:

```
ori   acc    acc_after   date1     date2         date3
1      1        1       20/08/20   21/08/20    25/08/20
1      2        1       22/08/20   22/08/20    26/08/20
2      1        3       22/08/20   23/08/20    25/08/20
```

and I want to sum them as a rate which the sumifs function in excel shows like this:

```
=SUMIFS(ori;date1<=21/08/20)+SUMIFS(acc;date2<=21/08/20)+SUMIFS(acc_after;date3<=21/08/20)
```

I can create the query of each sumifs function:

```
select sum(ori) from 
public.table 
where date1 <= '21/08/20'
```

what I don't exactly know is how to write the query of three sumif function.
How can I do it?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Use `case` expressions to do _conditional aggregation_.

Comment: In standard SQL you can use `sum(..) filter (where ...)` - which DBMS product are you using? ("SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want:

```
select (sum(case when date1 <= '2020-08-21' then ori else 0 end) +
        sum(case when date2 <= '2020-08-21' then acc else 0 end) +
        sum(case when date3 <= '2020-08-21' then acc_after else 0 end) +
       ) 
from public.table ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below -

```
select sum(ori)+sum(acc)+sum(acc_after) 
from public.table 
where date1 <= '21/08/20'
```

Comment: thankyou, but in this case the date column is also different